# Swift 4 Generics

Tags: xcode, generics, swift4, swift-protocols

I am trying to learn Swift 4 generics and have written some code that won't compile. I don't understand why. Here's the code:

```
protocol NodeType {
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype E
    var parent: T {get set}
    var children: [T] {get set}
    var item: E {get set}
    func getItem()->E
    mutating func setItem(_ newItem: E)
    func getParent()->T
    mutating func setParent(_ theParent:T)
    func getChild(at index:Int)->T
    mutating func insertChild(at index:Int, child: T)
    func find(_ node:T)->Int
}

protocol ItemType:Equatable {
    associatedtype E
    var payload: E {get set}
    func matches(_ item:E)->Bool
}

struct Item<E:Equatable>: ItemType {
    var payload: E
    func matches(_ item: E) -> Bool {
        return payload == item
    }
}

struct Node<T:NodeType, E:ItemType>: NodeType {
    var parent: T
    var children: [T]
    var item: E

    func getItem()->E {
        return item
    }

    func find(_ node: T) -> Int {
        for aNode in children {
            // ********************************************************************
            // the following line fails: Value of type 'T.E' has no member 'matches'
            if aNode.getItem().matches(node) {
            }
        }
    }

    mutating func setItem(_ newItem: E) {
        item = newItem
    }

    func getParent()->T {
        return parent
    }

    mutating func setParent(_ theParent:T) {
        parent = theParent
    }

    func getChild(at index:Int)->T {
        precondition(0..<children.count ~= index)
        return children[index]
    }

    mutating func insertChild(at index:Int, child: T) {
        precondition(0...children.count ~= index)
        if index == children.count {
            // append at end
            children.insert(child, at: children.endIndex)
        }
        else {
            children.insert(child, at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that aNode has type T constrained to NodeType and aNode.getItem() is type E constrained to ItemType, which contains the function matches. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is just that you've confused yourself by using the placeholder names `T` and `E` throughout. The `E` in this declaration:

```
struct Node<T:NodeType, E:ItemType>
```

... is not the `E` in this declaration:

```
protocol NodeType {
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype E
```

There is no reason to believe that NodeType's `E` is an ItemType adopter, or that it is Equatable.

This will be a lot more obvious to you if you pick different names for your placeholders in different generics (you can use the Refactor feature of Xcode to help you). For example:

```
protocol NodeType {
    associatedtype NodeTypeParent
    associatedtype NodeTypeItem
    // ...
}
protocol ItemType:Equatable {
    associatedtype ItemTypePayload
    // ...
}
struct Item<ItemPayload:Equatable>: ItemType {
    // ...
}
struct Node<NodeParent:NodeType, NodeItem:ItemType>: NodeType {
    // ...
}
```

Now you'll get the message

> Value of type 'NodeParent.NodeTypeItem' has no member 'matches'

which I think is a lot clearer.

Comment: For every `associatedtype` declaration in a protocol, and for every placeholder declared in angle brackets in a struct declaration, use a _different_ placeholder name. That way you won't confuse yourself like this.

Comment: Thanks, useful advice

Comment: Hang on, I've rewritten with totally different names, I'll post that to clarify.

Comment: Thanks and I will when I’ve had a chance to look at your answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at Matt's answer I realised that the fundamental structure of NodeType was wrong, this caused partly by my confusing generic placeholders. The code below now compiles.

```
fileprivate let NotFound = -1

protocol NodeType {
    associatedtype Node
    associatedtype Element:Equatable
    var parent: Node? {get set}
    var children: [Node] {get set}
    var item: Element {get set}
    func isRoot()->Bool
    func getItem()->Element
    mutating func setItem(_ newItem: Element)
    func getParent()->Node?
    mutating func setParent(_ theParent:Node)
    func getChild(at index:Int)->Node
    mutating func insertChild(at index:Int, child: Node)
    func matches(_ node:Node)->Bool
    func find(_ node:Node)->Int
}

class TreeNode<ThisNodeElement:Equatable>: NodeType {
    var parent: TreeNode?
    var children: [TreeNode]
    var item: ThisNodeElement

    init(withNode node:TreeNode, value:ThisNodeElement) {
        parent = node
        item = value
        children = []
    }

    init(root value:ThisNodeElement) {
        parent = nil
        item = value
        children = []
    }

    func isRoot() -> Bool {
        return parent == nil
    }

    func getItem()->ThisNodeElement {
        return item
    }

    func setItem(_ newItem: ThisNodeElement) {
        item = newItem
    }

    func getParent()->TreeNode? {
        return parent
    }

    func setParent(_ theParent:TreeNode) {
        parent = theParent
    }

    func getChild(at index:Int)->TreeNode {
        precondition(0..<children.count ~= index)
        return children[index]
    }

    func insertChild(at index:Int, child: TreeNode) {
        precondition(0...children.count ~= index)
        if index == children.count {
            // append at end
            children.insert(child, at: children.endIndex)
        }
        else {
            children.insert(child, at: index)
        }
    }

    func matches(_ node:TreeNode)->Bool {
        return node.item == item
    }

    func find(_ node: TreeNode) -> Int {
        let index = children.index { (thisNode:TreeNode) -> Bool in
            return node.matches(thisNode)
        }
        return index ?? NotFound
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting back!

Comment: I guess my remaining question is what the protocol is for. It doesn't seem to me to serve any function in the story. Why isn't this just a generic class, end of story? You could delete the protocol and remove the class's adoption of the protocol, and the class just compiles and does what you want.

Comment: Also, returning `index ?? NotFound` is not Swift-like. This is why God gave us Optional. The way to signal you didn't find something is exactly the way `index` signals it.

Comment: You are quite correct in both cases. As I said at the beginning of this thread I am trying to learn generics and have succeeded in vastly overcomplicating things. Things are much clearer now.

Comment: I wonder whether my own explanation of generics might prove helpful. My explanation and motivation for them is a little different from the way most people teach them. http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_generics Only very slightly outdated.